# How to delete an app that is running in background

Tags: background, blackberry

I've created an App that has 2 entry points. One runs in background, the other one handles the ui. I'm not able to delete this app. There is no delete in the menu like when clicking on other apps. I can't even find a way to delete it with advanced settings. The only way for me to remove it is the security delete which deletes ALL newly installed apps.

How can I delete that damn App? Is that related to the way I installed it (development via eclipse-plugin, no app world or bb desktop software)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create simple batch file `erase.bat`

```
rem Set valid path to your eJDE installation
set JDE=C:\java\BlackBerry\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.29\components
set PATH=%PATH%;%JDE%\bin

JavaLoader -u erase -f AppName.cod
```

Comment: Thanks... but I was more talking about a simple solution that every enduser can use.